# how to configure current directory when starting WSL distro via Windows Start Menu or pinned on Task Bar?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When installing a WSL (Linux) distro via the Microsoft Market Place, we get a default icon in the Windows Start Menu, with which to start it (e.g. "Ubuntu"). We can also pin that icon to the Task Bar. By default clicking this icon will start a (Bash) prompt in the Linux home directory `~`. How to change this to a different default directory?

*NOTE: Maybe a silly question, but when faced with this the obvious was overlooked by me. I hope this question will help others in the same situation that search for "WSL default directory" (and variations).*

Answer (score 0):

When clicking the distro icon you will get Bash. You can `cd` in to the desired directory in a Bash start up script. In the current "Ubuntu" WSL distro the `~/.bash_profile` file does not yet exist by default. Make sure to include `~/.bashrc` (which does exist by default).

```
cat <<EOF >~/.bash_profile
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
  . ~/.bashrc
fi
cd /mnt/c/my/
EOF
```

If you put the `cd` command in `~/.bashrc` instead, then it will also be run for subshells, which might not be what you want.